# Stop the toast while quitting the app

Tags: android, toast

I was doing an application which uses some Toasts.

If a Toast appears and in the meanwhile I quit the app, it normally doesen't disappear.

Is there a way to stop the Toast if I quit the app on my phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In  Activity onStop or ondestroy use cancel() method

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Toast toast = null;

@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    showMyToast();
     }


   public void showMyToast()
   toast.setText(" test toast");
            toast.show();
  }

@Override
protected void onStop () {
    super.onStop();
    toast.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

while quitting from add need to write this

```
toast.cancel();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Toast.makeText` returns a Toast object. Call `cancel()` on this object to cancel it.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.cancel();
```

Answer (score 1):

use android activity life-cycle  and override onstop() or onPause mthodes

- **onPause()**    called when activity is not visible to the user.
- **onStop()** called when activity is no longer visible to the user.

  ```
    @Override
     protected void onPause () {
      super.onPause();
      toast.cancel();
    }
  ```

or

```
@Override
     protected void onStop () {
    super.onStop();
    toast.cancel();
  }
```